# Nodejs express how to pipe stream from function to API res

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-s3, nodejs-stream

How do I pipe the stream from my `downloadWithBuffers` function into the `res` of my `sequence_stream` API? I can get the stream to work when I run the `downloadWithBuffers` function directly in the file passing in the `params` with correct bucket and object key but I cant seem to figure out how to pipe the results to the APIs `res`

I appreciate any help

```js
const S3 = require('aws-sdk').S3

const awsSettings = {
  region: 'us-east-2',
  accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
  secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
}

const s3 = new S3(awsSettings)

function downloadWithBuffers(params) {
  s3.getObject(params)
    .on('httpData', function (chunk) {
      console.log(chunk)
    })
    .on('httpDone', function () {
      console.log('Done streaming file')
    })
    .send()
}

module.exports = { downloadWithBuffers }
```

Controller for route and API

```js
const getStream = required('../functions/getStream')

// Serve stream for a specific image file.
exports.sequence_stream = (req, res) => {
  try {
    const params = { Bucket: '----', Key: '----' }
    getStream.downloadWithBuffers(params).pipe(res)
  } catch (error) {
    res.send(error)
  }
}
```